# Where did the Catholic Church condemn naming guardian angels?

Tags: catholicism, angels, guardian-angels

I was listening to episode 24 of the Catholic Man Show and they said (without citation) that the Catholic Church has condemned naming guardian angels. The reason they gave was because God gave man the authority over created things on Earth (Through Adam in Genesis). So what basis and where did the Catholic Church make this pronouncement. And should we burn our children's videos with a contrary teaching?  (i.e. CCC Video - My Secret Friend, A Guardian Angel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Where does the Catholic Church condemn naming guardian angels?**

You can find your answer from the **Congregation for Divine Worship and the Discipline of the sacraments** [Directory on Popular Piety and the Liturgy](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20020513_vers-direttorio_en.html), PRINCIPLES AND GUIDELINES:

> 217. Popular devotion to the Holy Angels, which is legitimate and good, can, however, also give rise to possible deviations:
>
>      - when, as sometimes can happen, the faithful are taken by the idea that the world is subject to demiurgical struggles, or an incessant battle between good and evil spirits, or Angels and daemons, in which man is left at the mercy of superior forces and over which he is helpless; such cosmologies bear little relation to the true Gospel vision of the struggle to overcome the Devil, which requires moral commitment, a fundamental option for the Gospel, humility and prayer;
>      - when the daily events of life, which have nothing or little to do with our progressive maturing on the journey towards Christ are read schematically or simplistically, indeed childishly, so as to ascribe all setbacks to the Devil and all success to the Guardian Angels. **The practice of assigning names to the Holy Angels should be discouraged, except in the cases of Gabriel, Raphael and Michael whose names are contained in Holy Scripture.**

Although this practice is discouraged, some of the faithful do in fact give a name to their Guardian Angels.